# How to make every action in a zend (1.12) controller return JSON?

Tags: json, zend-framework

I have a controller that is purely for API use (no view or layout).

I want every action to return JSON format and have the Content-Type in the response be `application/json`.

I could achieve the header part by using the controller `postDispatch()` but couldn't find a way to do `json_encode()` from single place (I know I can do it from every action however I wanted it to be centralized).

I have even tried to use a plugin and there to manipulate the request body but for some reason that is not clear to me it is always empty.

Currently my solution is as follows:

```
public function init()
{
    // no Layout
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    // no views
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
}

public function indexAction()
{
    $data = array("likes","to","sleep");
    echo Zend_Json::encode($data);
}

public function postDispatch()
{
    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
}
```

Now, if i only managed to do the `echo Zend_Json::encode` in one single place...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`ContextSwitch` action helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html)

> The JSON context sets the 'Content-Type' response header to 'application/json', and the view script suffix to 'json.phtml'. By default, however, no view script is required. It will simply serialize all view variables, and emit the JSON response immediately.

You will need to register it within the controller.

```
class FooController extends \Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function init()
    {
        $contextSwitch = $this->_helper->getHelper('contextSwitch');
        $contextSwitch->addActionContext('list', 'json')
                      ->addActionContext('bar', 'json')
                      ->initContext('json'); // json arg here means that we only allow json
    }
}
```

You would then need to pass the `format` parameter in the url `/module/foo/bar/format/json` or as a query parameter `?format=json`

Comment: use setActionContext instead of addActionContext, it will remove the unneeded contexts

Comment: i want to be able to get the same result with a nice Uri - without the format=json format/json.

Comment: You can avoid passing `format` in the request by setting the default context:  `$contextSwitch->setDefaultContext('json');`

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own [controller plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.plugins.html).

In `preDispatch` turn off layout and view renderer and in `postDispatch` set content-type header in response.

Next option is to assing data to view.

```
public function indexAction() {
    $data = array("likes","to","sleep");
    $this->view->assign('data', $data);
}
```

and in view script call [json view helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.json) `<?php echo $this->json($this->data);` and do not use layout.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it less elegant.  I don't want to add view

Comment: Then make controller plugin.

Comment: Again,  I will need to pass the format in the uri. It's not restful.